# Spring dependencies modules don't merge application.yml

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm working on project with multiple autoconfigure modules (ex: mongo-autoconfig, webclient-autoconfig, ...). Apps module add autoconfig via pom dependencies.

According to Spring doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.wildcard-locations

> By default, Spring Boot includes config/*/ in the default search locations. It means that all subdirectories of the /config directory outside of your jar will be searched.

we have added application.yml for each autoconfig in a config subpath (ex config/mongo/application.yml, config/webclient/application.yml, ...).

When app start local config, profiles config are loaded but not autoconfig properties. when i move file in config/ path only one properties file is loaded. I've tried to play with:

```
spring.config.location
spring.config.additional-location
spring.config.import
```

No more success...

In fact, i'm trying to do this without add X spring profiles:

[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBB8n.jpg)

Project is in Java 11, Maven, Spring boot 2.7.12

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. THere can be only 1 file at 1 location. So no it will not merge them together, it will also load only `application.yml` (and profile specific ones) directly under `/config` not in a subdirectory.